# Why did I just get the Announcer Badge and the Booster badge?

Tags: support, badges, publicity-badges

Today I got both the Announcer badge and the Booster badge for [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123071/why-isnt-rich-code-formatting-more-common) that I asked last year.

I don't remember ever sharing a link to it, and it seems odd to me that I would get both badges in one day, implying that there were at least 276 people who viewed it today from a link I don't remember ever sharing.

What's going on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your question was linked using your user ID from the on-going [Stack Exchange segment on Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/09/should-i-continue-teaching-myself-how-to-code-or-should-i-go-pro/), as the "See also" link under the "Challenge Yourself" answer. Admittedly I'm not entirely sure I get how your post relates to the chosen answer, but it does explain the traffic.

Comment: ...how the heck did you find this out?

Comment: I have my ways, I have my ways...

Comment: I also knew that it had to have been shared from a place with reasonably high visibility and that that article ran today, so it was a likely (and correct) candidate. Apparently [searching for the title](https://www.google.com/search?q="Why+isn't+rich+code+formatting+more+common%3F"&oq="Why+isn't+rich+code+formatting+more+common%3F") brings it up as the ninth result now, too.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone like me who got the announcer badge and DIDN'T get posted on Ars Technica, didn't have any activity on the question for which the badge was received, and didn't remember even looking at it, let alone linking to it....

I got an announcer badge for [a question about testing cron](https://askubuntu.com/q/85558/457111) on Ask Ubuntu.  Huh?

I mostly frequent Unix & Linux, so I guessed I must have posted a link in a comment to that question.  Did I?

[Yes, I did!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49419/manually-run-a-cron-job-simulate-running-cron-job#comment441706_49419)  I found it by running a Data Explorer query like so:

```
select * from comments
where
text like '%85558/457111%'
and
userid = 135943
;
```

(Note that the actual comment included "http" whereas the current "share" link is "https," which is why I first got no results and then used the URL substring as shown to search.)

---

[Here is existing SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/273888/search-inside-comments-of-specific-user-now-case-insensitive), just put your user ID and text to search and you'll get the results.