# Why did I get the Announcer?

Tags: support, badges, publicity-badges

Recently (5h ago) I got the Announcer awarded for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966826/save-and-render-a-webpage-with-phantomjs-and-node-js). That's fine, thank you; the only problem is I don't remember to have any activity related to that question, let alone posting the link to it somewhere. I know that 'question sharing' works in strange ways sometimes, still would be great to understand how it worked in this case. )

*(yes, I checked [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145673/why-did-i-just-get-the-announcer-badge-and-the-booster-badge); but in that case, the question itself was of the OP)*

Comment: I wonder didn't someone just mistype the link, using my ID instead of theirs? That would explain it.

Comment: Yes, Cant find any link you shared on that question. Kindda odd.

Comment: Of all possible Q+A share links (with your user id), Google claims only `http://stackoverflow.com/a/9978162/1229023` is used—[on that very same page](https://www.google.com/#q=http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fa%2F9978162%2F1229023). I cannot find it there today, nor in Google's cache. Also, sharing within the network itself doesn't get you any badge. But once you use such links within SE then others might copy it. Maybe a comment with a link you deleted? But even then Google or [Topsy](http://topsy.com/trackback?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fa%2F9978162%2F1229023) would often find it.

Comment: Probably the same issue as [Publicity badges might be taking internal links into account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134185/publicity-badges-might-be-taking-internal-links-into-account)

Comment: [answer at Programmers meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6052/31260 "Strange badge award") explains similar issue as follows: "I had the same thing happen to me. This is because of arstechnica.com. When they do a piece on some recent Stack Exchange discussions, they include some links. Those links will use the id of the featured user as the "share-id". Your answer has been featured... So when visitors click those links, they count as your share..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11260463/897024) you are linking to an answer in the question [Save and render a webpage with PhantomJS and node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966826/save-and-render-a-webpage-with-phantomjs-and-node-js/9978162#9978162). It can be easily found in the list of linked questions from the sidebar.

Links from within the SE network shouldn't count towards the badge. Maybe the question got crawled and mirrored somewhere. Another possible explanation is in the question @psubsee2003 posted in the comments; Some people may just disabled the HTTP referer header field. Similar to this some people could have bookmarked the shortlink from the answer.

Comment: All hail the almighty system!

Comment: I didn't think you could get the announcer badge for internal links?

Comment: Ah, found a year old bug report: [Publicity badges might be taking internal links into account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134185/publicity-badges-might-be-taking-internal-links-into-account)

Comment: I suspect the "mirrored somewhere" suggestion is probably the key here.

Comment: That solves this specific case, but what about other users? Is there any way for an average user to find where we linked a question?