# Got Announcer badge for linking within SE

Tags: bug, publicity-badges

[I just got Announcer badge on Meta Code Golf.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/announcer?userid=2800)

I shouldn't get it :-) I linked that question from the main CodeGolf site. I am 100% certain that I linked this question only within SE. Why would I link this very particular question from the outside webs?

Is this a bug or a feature?

I think it shouldn't be like that - you should be awarded for your effort *outside* to let people know about SE. Linking within SE is valuable, but I feel these badges are intended for propagating SE and it should be consistent in that.

**EDIT:** thanks to the discuters. [Got an idea for possible solution.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218424/166308)

Comment: It only counts people who clicked the link, it doesn't matter where the link actually was. I assume this is how it's designed.

Comment: *sshhh* thats [not supposed to happen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188733/220332) but I like it better that way

Comment: The badge is supposed to be for external visitors.  But there've been cases when a link you posted internally (with your user info for the badge) was grabbed by a scraper and the external visitors have come from the scraper's site.

Comment: @psubsee2003 perhaps they can figure out from the logs..

Comment: @Tomas unless you did it through fraud, the badge won't get reversed anyway.  And there may still be a bug, but the few cases of this I've seen a explanation for are usually related to scrapers.

Comment: You get credit for internal links from users who disable the `referer` header in their browser, because then the system can't tell.

Comment: And for another possible reason: [Why did I just get the Announcer Badge and the Booster badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145673/why-did-i-just-get-the-announcer-badge-and-the-booster-badge)