# Got a badge (Announcer), have no idea how I got it

Tags: discussion

I just received a badge ([Announcer](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/57/announcer)) for [this question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94060/run-adduser-non-interactively). 
I don't think I visited this question before, let alone share it.

When I click on the share button, it gives me a link with my user id. This means that anyone can easily increase someone else's visit amount, and I think this might be how I got these visits. I don't really think this is a security issue (but still tagged it, it weirded me out when I saw the notification). I love earning badges, but only when I actually earned them.

Comment: well, this is close but not close enough: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145673/why-did-i-just-get-the-announcer-badge-and-the-booster-badge/299585#299585

Comment: Somewhere out there a link exists with your userid at the end. Where it is and how it was created there remains a mystery then.

Comment: @rene I am pretty curious. Is there a way to find it? Tried googling the link, but that didn't help.

Comment: You could try [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/). Or search chat. Keep in mind there have been reports that this happened because a Crawler added a sequence number when they visited a post. The only people who might know is an SE dev but they are not going to sift through logs to find the referrer of visitors of that question.